# Return in callback?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to `return` after testing the connection to my database, so that it won't run the rest of my script. Will this be possible?

First function that i call

```js
    testcon: function (callback)
    {
        var con = mysql.createConnection({
            host: sqlhost,
            user: sqluser,
            password: sqlpass,
            database: sqldb
        })
        con.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) {
              return callback(false)
            }
            return callback(true)
        });
    }
```

I call it here

```js
    db.testcon(function (result){
        if(!result && msg.content.startsWith("!"))
        {
            return msg.channel.send("I'm not connected to my main database. I can't do anything for you, as of now. :(")
        }
    })
    console.log("He ran me, ti-hi.")
```

I don't want theb"console.log()" line to be executed, however it does. How can I go around this?

Comment: If you only want the script to run based on an async value, you need to start the rest of you script from the callback: `if(!result && msg.content.startsWith("!")){...} else {...do the rest}`

Comment: There's no better way to do this? Seems kinda ridiculous

Comment: It's part of the bargain we make to get fast single-threaded apps that don't block. It's common to put your main code in a function and call it from your init callback. You can also use promises and async/await to make things look a little more linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this seems ridiculous to you (the words you used in your comments), that's because you don't yet understand how asynchronous operations in node.js work, how inline asynchronous callbacks work and how you program with it in node.js to accomplish your task.  I would suggest you do some more reading about how node.js is event driven, how it runs Javascript as single threaded, how it uses non-blocking I/O operations and how one programs with that.

Node.js does network I/O using non-blocking, asynchronous operations.  That means the rest of your code continues to run while an asynchronous operation is underway and whatever you need to do when that asynchronous operation is completed should be done IN THE CALLBACK itself (or in some function you call from the callback).  This is how node.js works.

There are more advanced tools than plain callbacks such as promises and then `async` and `await` used with promises, but the asynchronous architecture remains and all these concepts remain.

In your particular case, you need to put any logic that you want to happen after the operation completes inside the callback itself.

```
testcon: function (callback) {
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: sqlhost,
        user: sqluser,
        password: sqlpass,
        database: sqldb
    });
    // just communicate back the error, allow the caller to see the actual error
    con.connect(callback);
}


db.testcon(function (err) {
    if(err) {
        msg.channel.send("I'm not connected to my main database. I can't do anything for you, as of now. :(");
    } else {
        // log here so it happens when the connect has completed
        console.log("He ran me, ti-hi.");
    }
});
```

Also keep in mind that executing a `return` inside a callback returns ONLY from that callback.  It does not `return` from any higher level function that you may have been called from.  And, if the callback you put the `return` in is an asynchronous callback, then the higher level function you were called from has probably already returned and moved on. It didn't wait for this non-blocking callback to get called.

Comment: Aha, i see, it's all part of my learning process with this and it got me really confused as i am used to other languages. I'm just really thankful that i can go here and ask for help if i don't particularly can find anything or name what i am looking for. Thank you so much for giving me an in-depth answer. Much appreciated!